# Calling function from another function in ionic2

Tags: ionic2

i want to call set function from var success function.
how to do this not able to use this.set()
getting this error http://prntscr.com/j1il36
please help

```
   set(otp){
        alert(otp);
     this.otpData.otp = localStorage.getItem('otp');

   }

   smsRead(){



   var options = {
     delimiter : "OTP is",
     length : 6,
     origin : "ENTIND"
   };

   var success = function (otp) {


     this.set(otp);

     localStorage.setItem('otp', otp) ;
     OTPAutoVerification.stopOTPListener();

   }

   var failure = function () {
     OTPAutoVerification.stopOTPListener();
     alert("Problem in listening OTP");
   }

   OTPAutoVerification.startOTPListener(options, success, failure);


   }
```

Comment: change `var success = function (otp)` to `var success = (otp) =>`. You should use arrow function here to get the right context of `this`